# Moving callback function to a class causes an error!

Tags: c++, callback

After I moved some OpenGL code from main function to a new class I had the following error on the following row:

```
glutDisplayFunc(OnDisplay);
```

> error C3867: 'Room::OnDisplay': function call missing argument list; use '&Room::OnDisplay' to create a pointer to member

What was my fault ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glutDisplayFunc` expects a `void (*func)(void)`, but you're passing in a `void (Room::*func)(void)`.

Since class methods receive an implicit `this` parameter, their pointer types are fundamentally different than regular function pointers. There's no conversion possible between them.

All you can do is make `OnDisplay` a static member of `Room`. From there you can forward the call to a member function of a concrete Room instance (since there is by design only one glut display callback and you migrated from procedural code, I presume you have only a single `Room` object somewhere).

Comment: I can't make it static because it has a specific signature and there are some members are called inside its body.

Comment: You can use a static function to forward the call to a concrete object, as I've written (obviously this defeats the purpose of having a class in the first place, but that's a different battleground).

Comment: Yes, seems you've unserstood the problem, I'll try anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you make a central manager class which keeps track of all active Room instances and dispatches the display callback to all of them. That's more or less the only way out.

Answer (score 2):

`glutDisplayFunc` just takes pointer to the function. When moved `OnDisplay` to the class, you will also pass the hidden argument `this` to `glutDisplayFunc` when actually get called.

One possible solution is to make `OnDisplay` as a static method.